# ExtJs 4.2: Override every Txtbox set value using common method

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4, overriding, decode

I have more than 50 text box in my ExtJs application. after develop my ExtJS application i realize there was a bug.
Edit mode every textbox view encode value of html(special char encode like `&lt;saman` for `<saman`)

What is most perfect(or best) soultion for avoid view HTML encode value form Text box my ExtJs application.

Before my application load i try to override ExtJs textbox setValue as bellow but that not affected all text filed

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Base, {
    setValue: function(val) {
        val = Ext.util.Format.htmlDecode(val);
        return this.callParent([val]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 4, overrides have a different syntax

```
Ext.define('App.Textfield.Override', {
    override :'Ext.form.field.Text',
    setValue: function (value) { 
        //your code...
        //this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: I try with your code but value return as undefined for window popup and form textbox

Comment: @user881703 It works fine in a JS fiddle for me. I think you are using the code in a way you are not telling us. `value` may be undefined if `setValue` was called with an undefined parameter...